# assignObject:toPersistentStore: breaking out of a loop

Tags: ios, core-data, persistent-storage

In an iOS app of mine I have the following code, itself inside a loop:

```
NSLog(@"Before context assignObject:toPersistentStore:");
[context assignObject:newXplainItem toPersistentStore:theStore];
NSLog(@"After context assignObject:toPersistentStore:");
```

The first NSLog is executed, but the second is never.
And the rest of the loop is never executed either (like if there was a break statement).
But the app does not crash.

The second line (assignObject:toPersistentStore:) looks like many other similar lines I am using inside the same program.

Anyone could make a guess on what may be wrong?
I guess the information I provide here is limited. But I don’t really know what else to write.

Comment: Could be an exception that is being possible ignored up the stack.  Set a breakpoint there and see where it takes you.

Comment: Maybe. See my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else hit the same problem. Here is what I did wrong:
In the data model, I forgot to assign the entity to the proper store.
Strangely enough that doesn't generate any error.